# What is the best touch screen kiosk solution?

Tags: usb, firefox, cd-command, vpn

I'm a web developer and I'm looking for the best stripped-down linux experience that provides a full-screen experience for touch screens. I'll be looking for:

- a robust experience that stops people loading up porn or logging out
- booting from USB, CD, HDD or all three if possible
- remote admin (probably via VPN)
- complete screensaver and power-save control
- the ability to hide cursors
- an onscreen keyboard, usually web-based for the customer but a native version for admin
- the ability to autorun 3D fullscreen apps such as Blender games
- possibly multi-touch functionality in the future but this isn't a deal-breaker

My favourite options at the moment are:

- [SLAX](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aUMUYQAMpwZsJ%3awww.ehartwell.com/InfoDabble/HowTo%3a_Create_a_boot-from-CD_browser_kiosk_with_Firefox_and_Linux+create+a+linux+kiosk&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&source=www.google.co.uk)
- Webconverger

This [kiosk project](http://kiosk.mozdev.org/) looks worth using too.

Could I get some recommendations for the best configuration please? Thanks

Comment: A bit late, but have you looked at Arch Linux? It's about as stripped as you can get, and the killer package manager and user script repository might have things you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [JWZ's kiosk hack](http://www.dnalounge.com/backstage/src/kiosk/) - at the very least, it's an interesting read.